# Azure function with docker image throwing throws missing connection string error even though present

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a custom docker image that I am trying to run azure functions on and I managed to get the function running but the code throws the following error

```
: Host.Startup[515]
      A host error has occurred during startup operation '48758bfd-0fc4-4ac1-bcba-042a0338e561'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'analysis_SERVICEBUS' is missing or empty.
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.ServiceBusAccount.get_ConnectionString()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener..ctor(String functionId, EntityType entityType, String entityPath, Boolean isSessionsEnabled, ServiceBusTriggerExecutor triggerExecutor, ServiceBusOptions config, ServiceBusAccount serviceBusAccount, MessagingProvider messagingProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListenerFactory.CreateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Triggers.ServiceBusTriggerBinding.CreateListenerAsync(ListenerFactoryContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.ListenerFactory.CreateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs:line 426
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.HostListenerFactory.CreateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\HostListenerFactory.cs:line 67
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ListenerFactoryListener.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\ListenerFactoryListener.cs:line 45
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ShutdownListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\ShutdownListener.cs:line 29
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\JobHost.cs:line 103
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/ScriptHost.cs:line 256
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebJobsScriptHostService.UnsynchronizedStartHostAsync(ScriptHostStartupOperation activeOperation, Int32 attemptCount, JobHostStartupMode startupMode) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/WebJobsScriptHostService.cs:line 266
```

On my local.settings.json I have already specified the connection string

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=false",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "UI_URL": "http://localhost:8080/report/",
    "analysis_SERVICEBUS": "my connection string is listed here "
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 9991,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  }
}
```

Is there something more that I need to do with my docker image to make the code run ?

Answer (score 0):

In your json configuration, you have analysis_SERVICEBUS nested under Values. It should be in the root of the json.

```
{

    "analysis_SERVICEBUS": "Endpoint=sb://xxxx="

}
```

Comment: Hi, That didn't work. I imagine it has something to do with my docker image.